# How to upgrade Python version to 3.9 on Vertex AI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am unable to upgrade my Python version to 3.9 on Vertex AI on GCP - I tried the methods outlined in several questions but they did not make for it - is there anyone who can help with this ?

Thanks

I tried updating the environment variables and installing Python 3.9 using the terminal but that did not seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The notebooks use Python 3.7 however, there are 2 alternatives to use python 3.9 in your Vertex AI user-managed notebooks:

**Method 1:**

You can use a custom image when creating the notebook. This way you can have the python version you prefer installed, as well as any dependencies you need preinstalled. On the creation view select the custom container option in “environment” so you can enter the route. You can find a guide with all the steps detailed [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/custom-container).

In the case you don’t have a custom container image created yet, you can find a guide on how to build your container image [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containers), the guide contains explanations on using yaml or json.

**Method 2:**

A more straightforward solution would be to use a Conda environment with the desired Python version and use that environment as a kernel in any Jupyter notebooks.
You can follow the below steps to create a Conda environment and a kernel from it. If you are using the terminal inside the Vertex AI notebook, you will need to activate the environment before executing any commands by using command `conda activate my-env` the environment name shout appears in brackets in the command prompt `(my-env) jupyter@jupyter:~$`.

```
# 1. Open the terminal in the JupyterLab environment
# 2. Create a new conda env called “python39” (you can change it if you want):
$ conda create -n python39 python=3.9 -y
 
# 3.Activate your new Python 3.9 environment:
$ conda activate python39
 
# 4. Install ipykernel when logged in the new env:
(python39)$ conda install ipykernel
 
# 5. Install jupyter
pip install jupyter
 
# 6. Create kernel with name "python39-kernel":
ipython kernel install --name "python39-kernel" --user
 
# 7. List kernels
jupyter kernelspec list
```

Select the kernel named `python39-kernel` and check the version of python. It will show 3.9.

This is an easy workaround but it might imply some issues on a long term basis, currently I believe there is no way to change the base Python version other than using custom containers.